# Link "Ver en Google Maps"

Tags: angular, ionic, google-maps

Estoy trabajando con Angular Google Maps (Agm) ya marque un punto de interés, pero quiero que ese punto de interés tenga un link que me permita llegar a ese destino.

En los otros puntos que aparecen en el mapa existe algo así:
[image: ☺]

Lo que quiero es poner el link azul que dice "Ver en Google Maps" y que naturalmente me abra Google Maps para poder hacer mi ruta de llegada al punto.

En este momento tengo esto:

```
    <agm-marker
      [latitude]="lat"
      [longitude]="lng"
      (markerClick)="clickedMarker(infowindow)">
      <agm-info-window #infowindow>
        <strong class="labelMaker">Categoría: </strong><br />
        <strong class="labelMaker">Nombre: </strong> <br />
        <strong class="labelMaker">Teléfono: </strong><br />
        <a target="_blank"
          jstcache="6"
          href="https://maps.google.com/maps?ll=9.988127,-84.760585&amp;z=17&amp;t=m&amp;hl=es-ES&amp;gl=US&amp;mapclient=apiv3&amp;cid=12309279456391267749"
          tabindex="0">
          <span>Ver en Google Maps</span>
        </a>
      </agm-info-window>
    </agm-marker>
  </agm-map>
```

lo saque inspeccionando un "Ver en Google Maps" que si funciona, pero lo que no se es que poner en el `href` para que me abra mi punto de interés en el Google Maps

Comment: Por cierto, no funciona solo cambiando la longitud y latitud ☻

Answer (score 0):

así lo solucione:

```
<agm-map [latitude]="lat" [longitude]="lng" [zoom]="17">
<agm-marker
  [latitude]="lat"
  [longitude]="lng"
  (markerClick)="clickedMarker(infowindow)"
  [iconUrl]=""
>
  <agm-info-window #infowindow>
    <strong class="labelMaker">Categoría: </strong><br />
    <strong class="labelMaker">Nombre: </strong> <br />
    <strong class="labelMaker">Teléfono: </strong><br />
    <a target="_blank"
      jstcache="6"
      href='http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr={{lat}},{{lng}}&daddr={{lat}},{{lng}}'
      tabindex="0">
      <span>Ver en Google Maps ☺</span>
    </a>
  </agm-info-window>
</agm-marker>
```